# LINQ: Nullable object must have a value.

Tags: linq, sharepoint

Let me preface this by saying I'm a novice with LINQ, and that this is code that I didn't originally write but am trying to fix.  I've done a lot of research on this error, but I haven't found anything helpful yet.  In fact, this error sort of makes my head spin.  Anyway...

I have a LINQ query that is selecting some data from three SharePoint lists.  Here it is:

```
    private void loadPEGrid(int id)
    {
        dc = new SpEntityDataContext(SPContext.GetContext(this.Context).Web.Url);

        EntityList<ProductDocumentMapItem> dMaps = dc.GetList<ProductDocumentMapItem>("Product Document Map");

        object mappedItems = null;

        mappedItems = from m in dMaps
                      join p in dc.PEProducts on m.ProductID.Value equals p.Id.Value
                      join d in dc.ProductDocuments on m.DocID.Value equals d.Id.Value
                      where m.ProductID.Value == id && m.ProductType == "PE"
                      select new { 
                          p.Grade, 
                          d.Path, 
                          d.DocumentType, 
                          d.Title, 
                          d.Name, 
                          Language = d.Language.Title, 
                          m.Id, 
                          DocId = m.DocID };

        GridViewProducts.KeyFieldName = "Id";
        GridViewProducts.DataSource = mappedItems;
        GridViewProducts.DataBind();
    }
```

The following fields are nullable:

- m.ProductID
- m.DocID
- d.DocumentType
- m.Id

When I debug, none of this throws an error, but when the page loads it does:
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value

Does this mean that one of the fields I'm selecting is null, or one of the join fields?  Having checked the data, I don't think this is the case.  Let me know if you need any more info from me.

Comment: I wonder if dMaps is null

Answer (score 1):

> > System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value

This exception is thrown when you are trying to get [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) property of nullable type. So, that means one or more of following is true:

- At least one of objects in `dMaps` has property `ProductID` equal to null
- At least one of objects in `dMaps` has property `DocID` equal to null
- At least one of objects in `dc.PEProducts` has property `Id` equal to null
- At least one of objects in `dc.ProductDocuments` has property `Id` equal to null
- Exception raised not by query